# Rounding Up in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the value of 50/60 as 1.
However all the following returns 0

```
DECLARE @value decimal(10,2)
SET @value = 50/60
Select @value
SELECT ROUND(@value, 2) RoundNumber
SELECT CEILING(@value) CeilingNumber
SELECT FLOOR(@value) FloorNumber
```

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following script which explains the problem:

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(10,2)
SET @value = CAST(50 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(60 AS DECIMAL(10,2));
SELECT @value                         -- 0.83
SELECT ROUND(@value, 2) RoundNumber   -- 0.83
SELECT CEILING(@value) CeilingNumber  -- 1
SELECT FLOOR(@value) FloorNumber      -- 0
```

The problem with your assignment to `@value` is that it first is doing *integer* division.  This means that `50 / 60` will first evaluate to *zero*, due to integer truncation.  Yes, after this, you are storing into a `DECIMAL(10,2)`, but by then it is already too late, because you lost the decimal component.

In my suggestion above, I show that if you do division with proper decimals, then the calls to `CEILING` and `FLOOR` work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert in decimal or make 50 to 50.0 which decimal

```
  DECLARE @value decimal(10,2)
SET @value = CEILING(50.0/60 )
Select cast (@value as int)
```